# SQL function to separate a record into two records.

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have created date and resolved date in Table1. Both fields are included in one record.

```
ID                created_date                resolved_at
'1xxxx'           '18-04-2018'               '20-04-2018'
```

Is it possible that i may use custom SQL function to separate them into 2 records.

I want somehow output like this.

```
ID           date                Operation
1xxx.       18-04-2018.          Created
1xxx.       20-04-2018.          Resolved
```

Comment: Google mysql unpivot and read up on Union statement

Comment: Which dbms you are using mysql or postgresql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,created_date DATE,CASE WHEN CREATED_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'Created' end OPERATION FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT ID,resolved_at DATE,CASE WHEN resolved_at IS NOT NULL THEN 'Resolved' end OPERATION FROM TABLE1
```

You simply need to use **`CASE WHEN`** and according to which ever column is not null we will make that name as **`OPERATION`**.

You can check [**`SQL fiddle here`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b008/3)

Try above query.

It will help you.

Comment: Always use `UNION ALL` unless you want to incur the performance overhead of removing duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler solution is:

```
select id, created_date, 'created' as operation from t
union all
select id, resolved_at, 'resolved' as operation from t;
```